# ProgressiveLoading in Flowpaper Zine

Tags: javascript, flexpaper

I am using `Flowpaper Zine` `javascript` `api` for `PDF` viewer. The scenario is the Pdf are of more then 300 pages and it takes too much time for loading.

For that I read the `Flowpaper` doc. and I found the ProgressiveLoading property also they written:

> Please observe that this parameter has no effect in FlowPaper Zine.
>   Please use split page loading for large documents in FlowPaper Zine.

So, my question is how to use `split page loading`?

Comment: Did you find the answer?